# How does this implication follow? (Differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For an exam I have later today I am studying an old exam question which is accompanied by a solution. The question, and solution, are as follows:

Consider the following initial value problem:

$$x'(t) = (t + 1)e^{-x(t)}, t \geq 0, \text{with } x(0) = 1.$$

Multiplying both sides with $e^{x(t)}$ yields $x'(t)e^{x(t)} = t + 1$ and hence:

$$\int_0^t x'(s)e^{x(s)}ds + c = \int_0^t(s + 1)ds \implies e^{x(t)} = \frac{(t + 1)^2 - 1}{2} + e^{x(0)}$$

Therefore, the solution of the initial value problem is:

$$x(t) = \ln\biggl(\frac{(t + 1)^2 - 1}{2}\biggr), \enspace t \geq 0$$

The part that I don't understand is the '$\implies$' part. How does this integral imply this $e^{x(t)} =$ ... solution? I apologize if this question is very trivial, however my professor has uploaded no examples where more steps are shown, and I was unable to find a similar question here or on other websites. Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: That “$+c$” on the left-hand side shouldn't be there. You've just integrated both sides from $0$ to $t$, why would you then add $c$ to just one side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) Note, that the derivative of $e^{x(t)}$ is $x'(t)e^{x(t)}$. Hence, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
$$ \int_0^t x'(s)e^{x(s)} \, ds = e^{x(t)} - e^{x(0)} $$
(2) For the right hand side, just integrate,
$$ \int_0^t s+1\,ds = \frac{t^2}2 + t = \frac{t^2 + 2t}2= \frac{(t+1)^2 - 1}2 $$

Comment: Thank you so much! In my attempts to figure it out I made multiple (very dumb) mistakes. It was way more obvious than I thought.

Comment: Alternatively, integrate the right-hand side like this $\int (s+1) ds = (s+1)^2/2 + C$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remember $(e^{u(t)})'=u'(t)e^{u(t)}$

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that
$$
x’(s)\mathrm{e}^{x(s)}= \dfrac{d}{ds} \mathrm{e}^{x(s)}
$$
Which hopefully you can see means we can integrate it out.